# Redirect www.domain.com/post/ to www.domain.com/post.html wordpress htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to remove year and month and redirect my old post from google search from

here is my htaccess code

## BEGIN WordPress

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
Options -MultiViews
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/([a-z0-9\-/]+) https://newkannada.com/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But it appending .html to categories also

any help thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you _tell_ it to append `.html`. So the questions is: how do you tell posts and categories apart?

Comment: i want to append .html to posts only not categories

Comment: We understood that from your question, you do not have to repeat that. So: can you answer my question? If not, then how do you want to implement it?